# How to get table name for a simple Sequel Dataset object?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Ie, given a dataset object `ds = DB[:transactions].where{updated_at > 1.day.ago}` - no funny joins and stuff going on - how could I fetch the table name (`:transactions`) ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the first table in the dataset, you can use `ds.first_source`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a string you can do:

```
ds.first_source_table.to_s
```

If you want a symbol, just omit `.to_s`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example provided, I would do something like this.

```
ds.klass.name
```

That will return a string with the name of your table.